# Grub error: ubuntu and windows 8 = Error invalid signature

Tags: windows, grub2

I've recently installed ubuntu 13on a partition with windows 8 but i can't return on the  windows loader.
I got Error invalid signature when i select windows 8.However ubuntu works perfectly.

I've search on internet and tested a solution with os-proper but it's change nothing:

```
:~$ sudo os-prober  
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
/dev/sda1:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain

:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
done
```

for more details on the configuration:

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3f78334c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   715057151   357527552    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       715059200  1151722887   218331844    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1151723518  1465147391   156711937    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1151723520  1452771327   150523904   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1452773376  1465147391     6187008   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

thanks in advance.

EDIT1:
**~$ cat  /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=fr_FR
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-27-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-27-generic-advanced-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-27-generic-recovery-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-26-generic-advanced-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-26-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-26-generic-recovery-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-26-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-advanced-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-recovery-c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c516a53f-bfa3-4140-8a30-18967123caa2
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-/dev/sda1' {
    insmod ldm
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

edit 2:

```
**~$sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt**
**~$ sudo umount /mnt**
```

no problems

Comment: If you try to mount /dev/sda1, does it give you any errors? `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt;sudo umount /mnt`

Comment: Also, can you paste the contents of /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Comment: Yes, i've got errors, i add them on the EDIT.

Comment: The command is `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

Comment: Sorry, i corected this.

Comment: Did you by any chance buy this computer with Win 8? Your HDD isn't GPT but in the "invalid signature" thing sounds suspiciously like a secure boot thing. Did you perhaps convert your machine from GPT to MBR? An easy way to tell: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=2 | hd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool-

[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

and tell us how it goes.